# My android app crashes on every other phone than used for tests during development

Tags: java, android, crash

I was hoping someone can put me on a right track with my issue.

I developed this android app with target sdk 30 and min sdk 16. During the development I was using Android 9 (sdk 28) for test purposes and everything worked well. This app is meant to be used internally in my father's small business, so I didn't put this up on Play Store. I built .apk file instead and installed on my father's phone with Android 10 (sdk 29) and tried to run. It turned out that the app crashes without any error. The phone's screen just flashes for 0.1 sec and the app crashes. Then I tried to install the app on another (older) phone with Android 8 (sdk 27) but the app crashes as well.

My another guess was phone language - as I was testing the app on phone with English set and my father's phone had set Polish as default, but on testing phone after the language change the app still works and on my father's phone after the language change to English still crashes.

Does anyone have any idea what the issue can be? Has anybody run into this issue before?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

First error is working on min sdk 16, is just old.

The most common crashes are from permissions errors. Big names in the industry like Samsung have their on rules an limits.

Then you should debug your code on MainActivity with your dads phone to identify when is crashing.

Comment: My problem is I'm in other country, so I don't have physical access to the phone. The app has been tested on my father's employees phones (in total 5 phones) and it crashes on every single. Including the same brand (samsung) that the app works on. I have high believes it's about the language/region just don't have any clue where such an option would be set in my code. Funny thing is, if I change language on my phone it still works. Is that possible a file app-debug.apk would run only on device that was debugged through USB?